# CSS Animation in Safari

Tags: html, ios, macos, safari, css-animations

I have set up an animation for a logo to appear on the navigation on a new site. The animation has three SVG pieces and animates each into place. However, on Safari and iOS devices, the logo is missing the center piece.

I have used Animate.css for these basic animations and can't find out what is different about the middle piece. The animation code is:

```
@-webkit-keyframes fadeInDown {
         0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

100% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
 }
  }

@keyframes fadeInDown {
0% {
opacity: 0;
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
        transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}

100% {
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transform: none;
        transform: none;
}
}

.fadeInDown {
-webkit-animation-name: fadeInDown;
      animation-name: fadeInDown;
}
```

It works fine on Chrome. The example Animate.css animation works fine in Safari. Any help would be vastly appreciated. A live example can be seen here http://codepen.io/bubblegoth/pen/MYvXBp

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the animation doesn't work and so you don't see the `centerpart`. Just add `display: inline-block;` to `.armdelay` and `.centerpart` and everything works fine.

In webkit-based browsers (Safari), `-webkit-transform` is ignored on inline elements.

https://www.webkit.org/blog/130/css-transforms/

Comment: I've tried adding 'display: inline-block;' to both classes and the center piece is still not appearing. I'm baffled.

Comment: Can you provide a less bloated example of your problem without the whole navigation bar?